# Creating dynamic repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

Hi I am building an online sports goods shop,
I have this plan of loading in all Sports Type in the Home page, like Football,Cricket,Basketball etc
And the administrator can create a game at his own will,

**Here's the confusion**
**How do I display the SubCategories of each Game if clicked (inside the repeater).**
I thought of adding an `ImageButton` to it!! But then how do I link that Image Button to the games, i.e. when the user clicks the respective Image button -> The subcategories of that game should be displayed

For example:
 1. If I have games such as Cricket,Football etc.
 2. The Repeater should show all the games in the repeater
 3. When The User clicks on for instance Cricket
 4. I wish to load all subcategories of cricket goods such as the BAT,BALL,STUMPS etc.

I attempted this by loading the games in `Repeater` as shown in below code snippet:

```
       <asp:Repeater ID="RepDetails" runat="server" 
        ondatabinding="RepDetails_DataBinding">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table style="border: 1px solid #df5015; width: 500px" cellpadding="0">
                <tr style="background-color: #df5015; color: White">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <b>Type of Sports</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="background-color: #EBEFF0">
                <td>
                    <table style="background-color: #EBEFF0; border-top: 1px dotted #df5015; width: 500px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Category") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClick="ImageButton2_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

I've even added the `ImageButton` but confused about making it load the respective subcategories of that game!

Suggestions are welcome if there can be another work around which can be more effective..

Comment: -1: for using broken keyboard. Please check your shift/capslock - it seem to be randomly stuck as there huge number of all-caps text in your post. You can try to make sample smaller to make question better.

Comment: I had purposely done that to draw attention!

Comment: To link on imagebutton, for showing sub categories you can use ajax method to load the sub categories dynamically Or you may use `TreeView` Control.. Rest what you have asked is very broad question there are many ways actually..

Comment: Thankyou Harsh for your reply!! Could you let me a desription of how can I know which imagebutton has the user clicked for now atleast so that I can get working on this, I will also check out the treeView... thanks

Comment: @user2866238 you need to understand markdown formatting to highlight the text in proper format..; For me, using Caps in whole sentence does not highlight but instead distracts reader and shows low quality of question

Comment: Learn about some useful formatting from [markdown formatting link here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: you can use any way to identify the meta details of the record id either on `ImageButton` using `CommandArgument` property or using `Data- (data dash)` html attribute for easy use in js parts.. refer : [data-dash article here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/30/giving-data-to-javascript.aspx) and [jquery data dash method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) if requires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a nested repeater

In aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepDetails" runat="server" OnDataBinding="RepDetails_DataBinding">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="border: 1px solid #df5015; width: 500px" cellpadding="0">
            <tr style="background-color: #df5015; color: White">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>Type of Sports</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #EBEFF0">
            <td>
                <table style="background-color: #EBEFF0; border-top: 1px dotted #df5015; width: 500px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Category") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClick="ImageButton2_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="SportsProps" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color: #EBEFF0">
                    <td>
                        <table style="background-color: #EBEFF0; border-top: 1px dotted #df5015; width: 500px">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" OnClick="ImageButton3_Click" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In code behind

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            RepDetails.DataSource = GetData();
            RepDetails.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater repeater = ((ImageButton)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("SportsProps") as Repeater;
        Label catLabel = ((ImageButton)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("lblSubject") as Label;
        repeater.DataSource = GetDataDetail(catLabel.Text);
        repeater.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ImageButton3_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something to hide the 
    }

    private DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("category", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("1 ", "Basketball");
        dt.Rows.Add("2 ", "Football");
        dt.Rows.Add("3 ", "Soccer");
        return dt;
    }

    private DataTable GetDataDetail(string category)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("Bat");
        dt.Rows.Add("Ball");
        dt.Rows.Add("Stump");
        return dt;
    }
```